# AWS-CLI : Create RDS Aurora DB instance into existing cluster created from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Based on my research, I've found that the **only** way to create using CLI an Aurora cluster with instances inside it from an existing snapshot is to follow these steps:

1) Create snapshot from existing cluster

2) Launch cluster from snapshot

3) Add instance into cluster

Thus, the commands I ran using the most-up-to-date AWS CLI version are these (along with the outputs):

```sh
aws rds create-db-cluster-snapshot \
  --db-cluster-snapshot-identifier analytics-replica-db \
  --db-cluster-identifier prodcluster
```

which outputs

```
{
    "DBClusterSnapshot": {
        "Engine": "aurora",
        "SnapshotCreateTime": "2017-07-24T15:08:12.836Z",
        "VpcId": "vpc-ID",
        "DBClusterIdentifier": "cluster_name",
        "DBClusterSnapshotArn": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:aws_account:cluster-snapshot:analytics-replica-db",
        "MasterUsername": "db_username",
        "LicenseModel": "aurora",
        "Status": "creating",
        "PercentProgress": 0,
        "DBClusterSnapshotIdentifier": "analytics-replica-db",
        "IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled": false,
        "ClusterCreateTime": "2016-04-14T11:10:02.413Z",
        "StorageEncrypted": false,
        "AllocatedStorage": 1,
        "EngineVersion": "5.6.10a",
        "SnapshotType": "manual",
        "AvailabilityZones": [
            "eu-west-1a",
            "eu-west-1b",
            "eu-west-1c"
        ],
        "Port": 0
    }
}
```

After that, I create the cluster using this:

```
aws rds restore-db-cluster-from-snapshot \
  --db-cluster-identifier analytics-replica-cluster \
  --snapshot-identifier analytics-replica-db \
  --engine aurora \
  --port 3306 \
  --db-subnet-group-name this_is_a_subnet_group \
  --database-name this_is_the_database_name_equal_to_original_cluster_db \
  --vpc-security-group-ids this_is_a_random_security_group \
  --no-enable-iam-database-authentication
```

which outputs

```
{
    "DBCluster": {
        "MasterUsername": "this_is_the_same_username_as_the_one_on_original_db",
        "ReaderEndpoint": "this_is_the_new_RDS_endpoint_of_cluster",
        "ReadReplicaIdentifiers": [],
        "VpcSecurityGroups": [
            {
                "Status": "active",
                "VpcSecurityGroupId": "this_is_that_security_group"
            }
        ],
        "HostedZoneId": "Z29XKXDKYMONMX",
        "Status": "creating",
        "MultiAZ": false,
        "PreferredBackupWindow": "23:50-00:20",
        "DBSubnetGroup": "this_is_a_subnet_group",
        "AllocatedStorage": 1,
        "BackupRetentionPeriod": 10,
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "fri:03:34-fri:04:04",
        "Engine": "aurora",
        "Endpoint": "this_is_the_new_RDS_endpoint_of_reader",
        "AssociatedRoles": [],
        "IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled": false,
        "ClusterCreateTime": "2017-07-24T15:11:07.003Z",
        "EngineVersion": "5.6.10a",
        "DBClusterIdentifier": "analytics-replica-cluster",
        "DbClusterResourceId": "cluster-resource_id",
        "DBClusterMembers": [],
        "DBClusterArn": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:aws_account:cluster:analytics-replica-cluster",
        "StorageEncrypted": false,
        "DatabaseName": "this_is_the_database_name_equal_to_original_cluster_db",
        "DBClusterParameterGroup": "default.aurora5.6",
        "AvailabilityZones": [
            "eu-west-1a",
            "eu-west-1b",
            "eu-west-1c"
        ],
        "Port": 3306
    }
}
```

And now, all I want to do is just run this

```sh
aws rds create-db-instance \
  --db-name this_is_the_database_name_equal_to_original_cluster_db \
  --db-instance-identifier analytics-replica-instance \
  --db-instance-class "db.r3.large" \
  --publicly-accessible \
  --no-enable-iam-database-authentication \
  --db-cluster-identifier analytics-replica-cluster \
  --engine aurora
```

which outputs

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. Set database name for the DB Cluster.

Can someone PLEASE tell me why does it hate me?

Comment: Don't pass `--db-name` because that is set on the cluster, not the instance.  *"The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. [You can only] Set [the] database name for the DB Cluster [not the instance]."*

Comment: Thanks! Will give it another go in a few moments without `--db-name` on the cluster

Comment: You're right! I was understanding the error message poorly. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that is facing the same problem, some options are not available when you add a new instance to aurora cluster.

The error is tricky at the beginning, but it easy to understand. The last part, `Set database name for the DB Cluster.` indicates the real problem, and most of the time, you need to delete the property.

Another example `An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateDBInstance operation: The requested DB Instance will be a member of a DB Cluster. Set backup retention period for the DB Cluster.` you need to remove `--backup-retention-period`